# Get input value to ejb 3.1 throw interceptor

Tags: java, interceptor, ejb-3.1

Do you know if there is any way to log, throw an interceptor, the input values of the called method?

my actual interceptor is

```
public class Interceptor {
@AroundInvoke
public Object interceptor(InvocationContext invocationcontext) throws Exception{
    //Stampa prima del metodo
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.debug("Invoked method: "+invocationcontext.getMethod().getName());
    //here I would like to log also parameters. 
    try{
        return invocationcontext.proceed();
    } finally{
        log.debug("End of method: " + invocationcontext.getMethod().getName());
        log.debug(" duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }
}
}
```

The bean is

```
@Interceptors({Interceptor.class})
```

@Stateless
public class MrBean implements MrBeanRemote, MrBeanLocal {

```
/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public MrBean() {       
}

public void print(String in){
    System.out.println("Print: " + in);
}
}
```

So if i call the print method with in = "print that" the interceptor should log "print that". Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to log the parameters of your method, so you can use the getParameters() method on the InvocationContext :
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html#getParameters()

Comment: I tried log.debug(invocationcontext.getParameters().toString()); [Ljava.lang.Object;@f72802c4

Comment: sorry, i'm not able to edit to comment above... I wanted to say that I tried that log but it prints the string [Ljava.lang.Object;@f72802c4 and not the value of the parameters

Comment: @Gio : `invocationcontext.getParameters()` returns array of Object. You need to iterate over this array.

Comment: @Gio: Obscure is right, iterate over the array of values and you should find your parameters.
for (Object o : invocationcontext.getParameters())
{
log.debug(o);
}